# Please recommend a lightweight easily installable http server for OSX

Tags: macos, http, webserver

I need an http server to serve up static content on localhost.

It needs to meet the following conditions:

- easy to install, minimal configuration, just fire up from a directory and that's it
- supports OSX
- small memory footprint

Comment: Doesn't OSX have Apache built-in?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't check. But I wouldn't call it lightweight and very easy to configure

Comment: It can certainly be lightweight.  Easy to configure is another matter, but if it is already running, your configuration is done.  http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/12/07/apache.html

Comment: fair enough. That was easy. If you want to write up a small answer I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is built into OSX an can easily be enabled.

See http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/12/07/apache.html for some basic instructions.

Comment: I didn't read it through. All I did was go to "Sharing" in System Preferences, enable "Web Sharing", and I'm using my local ~/Sites as the directory. Pretty simple.

Comment: It'd be great to provide the instructions here rather than just linking somewhere! But as @Ovesh said, it can be condensed quite easily.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Python to run a simple http server. From the directory that you want to serve, run the following...

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

See this [Linux Jornal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) for more info.

Comment: What a great solution. It just works!

Comment: For python3, you can use `python3 -m http.server`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943751/what-is-the-python-3-equivalent-of-python-m-simplehttpserver

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MAMP](http://mamp.info).

It comes with Apache, PHP and MySQL, and sets it all up with a few clicks. Note that you should never use MAMP in a production environment; PHP & MySQL settings are optimal for development but there are some security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

A more current approach using Python3 (e.g. listening on localhost port 8080 and serving files form current directory):

```
python3 -m http.server --bind localhost 8080
```

Note: If you omit the `--bind` argument it defaults to **listen on ALL interfaces which is a security risk** as anyone connected to your network can request files.

Or it's also possible using `php`:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Python (and php) are not longer installed as part of the OS beyond MacOS 12.3, but they can be installed in a variety of other ways e.g using [`brew`](https://brew.sh/)).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat) for approaches using netcat/bash.